# Google Chrome like word search in Notepad++

Tags: text-editor, notepad++

Is there a plugin that makes it possible to do a Google Chrome like word search in Notepad++?

[image]

After a word search Google Chrome shows the approximate position of the line in which the word was found as a mark on the vertical scroll bar. There is a similar feature in eclipse. Is it possible to get a similar  feature in Notepad++ as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much for Notepad++, but I would recommend taking a look at [JN-NPP](https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin). Installation can be done via the Plugins Admin by searching for the jN Notepad++ Plugin. It can also be done by just placing the DLL, and the includes, in your plugins folder in the Notepad++ directory (highlighted [here](https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin/wiki/How-to-start)).

One of it's main features is the Smart Highlighting, which is essentially what you are looking for (on highlighting of a word, all occurrences will appear as green lines on the right hand side).

It also has a slew of other features, such as JSHint (A tool that points out errors in JS code), CSSLint (cleans up CSS code), a basic SVN client, a music player (for some reason), and many others.

Comment: Wow this is really cool thanks a lot
I have tested it in a portable installation of Npp V6.2.3 (UNICODE) and it works

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer provided (I know that I am, thanks and +1), then please accept the answer as a courtesy to others searching in future. Your comment helps, but is not immediately obvious. Thanks for good question (+1).